# R-module is semisimple iff every cyclic R-submodule is semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am asked to prove the following statement:

> An $R$-module $M$ is semisimple iff every cyclic $R$-submodule of $M$ is semisimple

The $\implies$ direction is trivial since every submodule of a semisimple module is semisimple

The other direction is more difficult since I do not see why for example $M$ cannot have the form 
$M=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}Rm_i$ where $Rm_i$ are all cyclic and simple as $R$-modules. What am I missing here?

Comment: It can have that form, as long as the $Rm_i$ are in finitely many isomorphism classes.

Comment: And in that case do I get a direct sum over these isomorphism classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other direction is still pretty straightforward, as long as you know a module is semisimple iff it is a sum of simple submodules.

A module is always the sum of its cyclic submodules.

If each of those submodules is semisimple, then the module is a sum of sums of simple submodules, hence it is a sum of simple submodules, i.e. semisimple.

---

Note: you wrote $M=\prod_{i=1}^\infty Rm_i$ when talking about semisimple modules. This is not correct. You should be aware that the product $\prod$ is a completely different animal from $\oplus$ when the index set is infinite. Semisimplicity of modules has to be proven with *sums* or *direct sums* but not products.

Comment: I wrote it exactly because then the statement wouldn't be true( we don't end up with a semisimple module), I mean how do we know that a module is always a direct sum of it's cyclic submodules? Can't there be an infinity of those? That's what I wanted to highlight and I am still confused about it. Do you have reference or proof for that result you mention?

Comment: The way I see it an $R$-module $M$ is always equal to $\prod M_i$ where $M_i$ are simple cyclic submodules but it remains to show that the $M_i$ are finite to conclude this is a direct sum

Comment: One thing at a time. 1) *I wrote it exactly because then the statement wouldn't be true* No, it does not make sense if you write with $\prod$. It is true if you write it with $\oplus$.

Comment: 2)   *how do we know that a module is always a direct sum of it's cyclic submodules?* I didn't say that. I said it was a **sum** of its submodules. Indeed it is *not always* a direct sum of cyclic submodules.  *Can't there be an infinity of those?* Yes. There can be. (...?)

Comment: 3) *The way I see it an -module  is always equal to ∏ where  are simple cyclic submodules*. This is not true. For example, if you take $M=\oplus_{i\in\mathbb N}F_2$, this is a countable set, but $\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}F_2$ is uncountable, so it could not be equal or isomorphic.

Comment: 4) *it remains to show that the $_$ are finite to conclude this is a direct sum*.  Based on this an 2) above, You seem to be under the impression that one may not write a direct sum with an infinite index set. That is incorrect.  A direct sum of any number of simple modules is semisimple, by definition. You do not need to (and indeed cannot) prove there must only be finitely many.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer everything! I will review the definitions again, I was under the wrong assumptions it seems

Comment: @nice_alg Awesome! Good luck